# input.innerHTML returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, html

I write html code this

```
<input type="text" class="inputstyle" id="text" name="text">
```

so this is JS code

```
function addtolist() {
//get input
var textappend = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
console.log(textappend);
console.log(typeof (textappend));
console.log(choice)
if (textappend != "") {
    choice.push(textappend); // append text to choice
}
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = choice; // output list 
}
```

And i make button if click button. Button will call `addtolist()` function and this function will append id="text"(type string) to the choice(brank array). I try input text "Hello World" to `<input>` but `addtolist()` function it's append blank string to choice. idk why help me solve it pls. (sorry for my grammar I don't english pro)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_

Comment: What's with that title

Comment: You want the `.value` property of the `<input>` element and not `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of a `<input type="text"` element, use `.value` rather than `.innerHTML`.

```js
var textappend = document.getElementById("text").value;
```

Comment: @CatDBB Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that you have a h1 inside HTML that contains the text that you want to use, you can just use `.value` instead of `.innerhtml`, I would suggest you to use it as your project gets bigger using `.innerhtml` may get complex so use `.value` instead.

This should be your JS code:

```js
function addtolist() {
//get input
var textappend = document.getElementById("text").value;
console.log(textappend);
console.log(typeof (textappend));
console.log(choice)
if (textappend != "") {
    choice.push(textappend); // append text to choice
}
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = choice; // output list 
}
```

Hope it helps out!